# Wordpress not displaying columns to hide/show on screen options

Tags: screen-options, screen-layout, screen-columns

I have installed Wordpress 5.8.3 which is at the moment the latest version available.
I'm trying to hide certain columns within the posts dashboard, but for some reason I doesn't have the option to do that, see:

[image]

As you can see I have only the pagination options, but the columns are missing.

I tried to disable all the plugins installed but same issue.

I also tried to reinstall wordpress, but same.

How can I fix that?

Comment: Are you sure everybody can Italian?

Answer (score 0):

I have also the latest version and the options are there
[image]
That should be some code doing that,in your theme functions.php file or in some plugin because wp have them.

You have there something call ninja popups, try to disable that plugin, the options should appear again, once I dont know that plugin, possibly that plugin have that options in the plugin options.

Comment: But I already have disabled all the plugins and same result. Could you suggest a wordpress hook that can hide the columns? In this way I will search the code snippet in the all the files

Comment: if all the plugins are disable, change theme, if it persists, I would install a new wp. the exact question you are asking I dont know yet. maybe someone will have more info about it